# declarations error in include and require functions

Tags: php, mysql, include

I write this code

```
include('database.php');

function get_something() {

database instructions

}

function get_another(){

database instructions

}
```

and I try to fix by this

```
function get_something() {
  include('database.php');
  database instructions

}

function get_another(){
  include('database.php');
  database instructions

}
```

I get redeclaration error .

how can I fix this ?

Thanks

Comment: Use `include_once`, functions in included files are declared globally AFAIK.

Comment: ...functions AND `define`itions :-)

Answer (score 3):

Either include all of your files at a point of your application that is guaranteed to be only executed once, or use `include_once 'database.php';`

Read up on it [here](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php).
Alternatively, you could implement [autoloading](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php). PHP will then load classes if, and only if, it needs them. It doesn't work for global functions (since they aren't classes), though. You'd have to wrap them in a class if you want to take advantage of this.

Answer (score 0):

Seperate configuration of the database and the functions in different files. 
Include the file with the functions first, only once (require_once is nice for this).

Then the database config where needed. This can be saved as returning an array for example

```
<?php
return array(
    'db1' => array(
        'user' => 'sdf',
    ),
);
```

and

```
$config = include 'config.php';
```

Thats the "quick fix now" method. But you really should use OOP, and autoload.